# TypeScript getting object value in iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, strict

I need to access the value of my object.

Object:

```
private filters: any = {
        id: {
            focused: false,
            options: true,
            value: null,
        },
        user_name: {
            focused: false,
            options: true,
            value: null,
        }
}
```

I'm iterating through them like this:

```
for (const [key, filter] of Object.entries(this.filters)) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(filter.value);
}
```

Problem is I can't reach the filter.value because "Object is of type unnown". I tried to set the object type to object instead of any. But after that I can't reach the filters object values like this:

```
this.filters.id.value = value;
```

It says

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you lazily typed your filters as `any`. You can fix this by defining an interface for the filters and then using that:

```
interface Filter
{
    focused: boolean;
    options: boolean;
    value: number | null; // TODO: type this
}
```

```
private filters: Record<string, Filter> = {
        // ...
}
```

The `Record` type specifies here that for every key of type `string` the value of the property has type `Filter`.

In this specific case you can also just drop the type annotation and the compiler will figure out that the shape of the filter objects is identical and that every filter has the `value` property. If the filters are not being created using an object literal that will no longer be an option, though.

Comment: Great, Record<string, Filter> was something new for me. It works.

Comment: @The50: It is a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), you can write it manually as `{ [key: string]: Filter }`.

Comment: Where could I put it? Inside my interface?

Comment: @The50: No, that would replace `Record<string, Filter>`. There is no need to; i was just spelling out how `Record` works internally. If you use an IDE with `go to definition` you can also jump to there and see it for yourself.